# Advice needed: ADSL and VPN for a small company

Tags: vpn, wifi, adsl, passthrough

I need advice on purchasing an ADSL modem/router for a small company.

At the moment, we are using the [iBurst Wireless](http://www.iburst.co.za/) service for internet connectivity. I have the iBurst desktop modem, which connects to my [Netgear WNR2000 router](http://www.netgear.com/Products/RoutersandGateways/WirelessNRoutersandGateways/WNR2000.aspx) via ethernet. I am using the Netgear WNR2000 to deploy a wireless network as well.

I have also set up a VPN using Windows Server 2003, and enabled the VPN Passthrough settings on the Netgear router. I am able to connect to the office network remotely without difficulty. However the problem that I've read is that the Netgear WNR2000 only supports VPN passthrough for a single session. This is simply not good enough. I need to be able to support at least 3 concurrent VPN connections immediately, and up to 5 in the near future.

Now I am cancelling my iBurst Wireless service and have just got my ADSL line installed. I have to purchase an ADSL modem, and now is a good time to think of future proofing my investment. I need a good ADSL modem, that will allow me to support at least 5 concurrent VPN connections, or more, without breaking the bank. My budget is about 150-200 USD.

I believe that my current Netgear WNR2000 router will be useless, except maybe to extend my wireless network in the future by a bit. Is there a solution where I can still use my Netgear WNR2000 for WiFi, for e.g., by connecting a cheaper non-WiFi ADSL modem to the Netgear router?

If not, then which WiFi-enabled ADSL modem/router that supports at least 5 VPN passthroughs can you recommend?

To sum it up, I need an ADSL modem/router that is:

- ADSL & ADSL2+ compatible
- has built-in 802.11n 270/300mbps WiFi (if having this feature doesn't push the price up too much)
- supports at least 5 VPN connections using VPN passthrough

**EDIT:** Answer 2.10 in the following FAQ has me a bit worried - [What is VPN/multiple VPN Pass-through?](http://www.ozcableguy.com/routerfaq.asp#2.10)

Answer (score 1):

Stick to your modem.

Then get an Mikrotik 750 o 450 or one of their G counterparts to do the routing for you. The modem stays working as modem only.

Then natuarllly you betterk now what you are doing - that is higher end pro stuff.

Comment: +1 for MikroTik recommendation. I've fallen in love with that routing gear.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be very tempted to look at a Cisco 877W.  They support ADSL and ADSL2+ (some even support Annex M), have builtin wifi (not n, but certainly a/b/g), and support up to 10 VPN tunnels.

You can probably pick one up on [ebay](http://is.gd/5ngJK) for a couple of hundred bucks no problem.

I'd be very tempted to use a seperate device for your wifi requirements.  Do you actually need 300Mbit wifi? 
I've never seen an 802.11n class device actually able to sustain 300Mbit throughput.
I understand the Cisco 887MW has support for 802.11n grade networking, but I think you'd be looking to pay considerably more. (Probably ~$600)

Answer (score 0):

DrayTek 2820N
http://www.draytek.co.uk/products/vigor2820.html
Apart from Wireless N, this is a Dual WAN router, supports ADSL/ADSL2, you can even get a cheap ADSL Modem and plug another ADSL line into the 2nd WAN port, or if you have a 2nd Cable Internet connection or a leased line terminating on Ethernet, that can directly go into the 2nd WAN Port of this router. Cost effective and feature rich...have never had any problems with DrayTeks - support is awesome. a 2820VN supports VOIP too, but as that is not your requirements you can get a 2820N. It also doesn't charges for any VPN Licenses, just a one off purchase and you are good to go.

```
Up to 32 Concurrent VPN Tunnels (incoming or outgoing)  
Tunnelling Protocols: PPTP, IPSec, L2TP, L2TP over IPSec  
IPSec Main and Agressive modes  
Encryption : MPPE and Hardware-Based AES / DES / 3DES  
Authentication : Hardware-Based MD5 and SHA-1  
IKE Authentication : Pre-shared Key and X.509 Digital Signature  
LAN-to-LAN & Teleworker-to-LAN connectivity  
DHCP over IPSec  
NAT-Traversal ( NAT-T )  
Dead Peer Detection (DPD)  
VPN Pass-Through
```

---

DrayTek 2955
This will require a ADSL Modem (can get a draytek too), have much more throughput, more vpn tunnels (`All in one price - no additional licenses`), robust firewall and DUAL WAN too.
http://www.draytek.co.uk/products/vigor2955.html

Both of the above routers will work either in `Failover` or `Load Balance` Mode, in LoadBalance Mode the router automatically load balances outgoing traffic on both lines. You can setup policies / firewall rules for specific traffic to go out via a specific wan port.

Hope that Helps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is anything of value on the network, you need a firewall. The protection from ADSL routers are barely sufficient for a consumer home network .. not for a business.

1/ Use whatever ADSL model the DSL provider gives you, and keep it on bridge/pass through mode.

2/ Get a good, solid, business class firewall.

- The [SonicWall TZ100](http://www.sonicwall.com/us/products/TZ_100.html) is excellent, and costs US$300.  There is an option for built-in wireless for another US$100. It offers both IPSec and SSL VPN, but only comes with 2 VPN licenses.
- The [Astaro Security Gateway 100](http://www.astaro.com/en-us/products/hardware-appliances/astaro-security-gateway-110) is also a top notch device. It costs a bit more, but has no separate VPN licensing. There is a separate Astaro wireless AP that is managed by the ASG available for around US$120.
- The [Cisco RV110W](http://reviews.cnet.com/routers/cisco-rv110w-wireless-n/4505-3319_7-34831247.html) looks interesting, although I have never used it, and I don't trust Cisco to be inexpensive even when they look it.